# CSS3 animation working in chrome and firefox but not in safari

Tags: css, google-chrome

so my css3 animation is working in chrome and firefox and not in safari and I was wondering if you could see the the problem in my code. I cannot seem to find why this is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.animated { 
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
animation-fill-mode: both; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn 
{ 
0% { 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3); 
} 

50% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); 
} 

70% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9); 
} 

100% { 
     -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
} 
} 

@keyframes bounceIn 
{ 
     0% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: scale(.3); 
} 

50% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: scale(1.05); 
} 

70% { 
    transform: scale(.9); 
} 

100% { 
    transform: scale(1); 
} 
} 

.bounceIn { 
-webkit-animation-name: bounceIn; 
animation-name: bounceIn; 
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="animated-example" class="animated bounceIn">
    <img style="position:absolute;margin:  auto;
    margin-left:41.5%;top:349px;width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:rgb(225,225,225);" src="../images/circleHat.gif"/>


        </div>
```

many thanks, any help is greatly appeciated

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that you're using a combination of two classes for this. Please also share the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: ofcourse, no problem

Comment: works for me windows 8 safari 5.1.7